# Aseprite ninja build error "cannot find -lSKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND"

Tags: linux, build, debian, ninja, skia

While trying to build Aseprite on Debian 10 (amd64) virtualbox VM, after building Skia, the `ninja aseprite` command returns the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
```

```
[1/1] Linking CXX executable bin/aseprite
FAILED: bin/aseprite 
: && /usr/bin/c++  -Wall -Wno-switch -O2 -g -DNDEBUG   src/CMakeFiles/aseprite.dir/main/main.cpp.o  -o bin/aseprite  lib/libapp-lib.a  lib/libclip.a  -lxcb  -lpthread  lib/libdio-lib.a  lib/libfilters-lib.a  lib/libflic-lib.a  lib/libtga-lib.a  lib/librender-lib.a  lib/libdoc-lib.a  lib/libfixmath-lib.a  lib/libui-lib.a  lib/liblaf-os.a  lib/liblaf-gfx.a  lib/liblaf-ft.a  /root/deps/skia/out/Release-x64/libskia.a  -lSKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfontconfig.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so  /root/deps/skia/out/Release-x64/libskshaper.a  lib/libobs.a  lib/libundo.a  lib/libcmark.a  lib/libjpeg.a  lib/libgiflib.a  lib/libwebpdemux.a  lib/libwebpmux.a  lib/libwebp.a  -lpthread  -lm  lib/libfreetype.a  lib/libharfbuzz.a  lib/libfreetype.a  lib/libharfbuzz.a  lib/libpng16.a  -lm  lib/libjson11.a  lib/libarchive.a  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so  lib/libfmt.a  lib/libtinyexpr.a  lib/liblauxlib.a  lib/liblua.a  lib/liblualib.a  lib/libupdater-lib.a  lib/libcfg-lib.a  lib/libver-lib.a  lib/libtinyxml.a  lib/libnet-lib.a  lib/liblaf-base.a  lib/libmodpbase64.a  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so  lib/libcurl.a  lib/libz.a  -ldl && :
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How may I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that CMake is looking for OpenGL and failing... Aseprite doesn't seem to use OpenGL anyway, so disabling that altogether by clearing the cache variable `SKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY` should work:

```
cd aseprite/build
cmake -DSKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY="" ..
ninja aseprite
```

I have tested it on Windows, but I'm not entirely sure if it will work on Linux...

Comment: Thanks for your help. It solved the opengl problem, but now it returns a lot of “undefined reference” errors. All functions have “Curl” and so do the variable/method/etc. the error is saying is not referenced. Probably it is something I missed along the way or haven’t done correctly, so I guess I’ll just buy the program... But again thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this. I got it to build on Ubuntu 20.04.

1. Follow the instructions to build skia over at the [skia git repository](https://github.com/aseprite/skia#skia-on-linux). Make a note of which folder you cloned the repository into, you will need it later. I tried using the pre-built binaries but I must have been doing something wrong and could just never get it work.
2. When the build is complete you will see a note about 32-byte alignment, and if you check the `out\Release-x64` folder you will see a `libskia.a` file. Now you know that skia was built succesfully.
3. Install the aseprite linux build dependencies with `sudo apt-get install -y g++ cmake ninja-build libx11-dev libxcursor-dev libxi-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libfontconfig1-dev`. You will find these instructions at the [aseprite git repository](https://github.com/aseprite/aseprite/blob/main/INSTALL.md#linux-dependencies).
4. Follow the instruction further down that page for the linux install but pay attention to the parameters you need to change regarding the location of that `libskia.a` file mentioned in point 2.
5. Before you start building (and why you're here) you need to enter @Ben_'s command given above to unlink the dependency to OPENGL (`cmake -DSKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY="" ..`)
6. Now proceed to build aseprite with as the rest of the build instructions given on its repo page with `ninja aseprite`
7. Now go to `aseprite/build/bin` and find the `aseprite` executable.
8. You can copy this `bin` folder to another folder, and run `aseprite` from there. You can then delete all of the sources you downloaded.
9. There will be a bunch of errors during the `python` step, and you'll notice it complains about not being able to find some repositories, I think `common.git` is one of them. You may safely ignore this warning.

If you want to keep supporting development of the application I do recommend you spend whatever it costs for a license (but it's totally legal to build your own copy like this).

Answer (score 0):

I typed in `opengl32.lib` in `SKIA_OPENGL_LIBRARY` and it compiled and ran successfully